# Opening hours in array from monday to sunday, sort it from today instead of monday

Tags: php, arrays, date

I seem to have a problem, understanding how to sort my array the way i want to.

At the moment my array is like this, each index represent a weekday starting from monday.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 08:00-18:00 // monday
    [1] => 08:00-18:00 // tuesday
    [2] => 08:00-18:00 // wednesday
    [3] => 08:00-18:00 // thursday
    [4] => 08:00-18:00 // friday
    [5] => 10:00-14:00 // saturday
    [6] => 10:00-14:00 // sunday
)
```

Let's say today is saturday, I need the array to look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10:00-14:00 // saturday
    [1] => 10:00-14:00 // sunday
    [2] => 08:00-18:00 // monday
    [3] => 08:00-18:00 // tuesday
    [4] => 08:00-18:00 // wednesday
    [5] => 08:00-18:00 // thursday
    [6] => 08:00-18:00 // friday
)
```

What i want is to show the opening hour for today.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following logic might sit well with what you're trying to accomplish:

```
<?php

$arr = ["08:00-18:00", "08:00-18:00", "08:00-18:00", "08:00-18:00", "08:00-18:00", "10:00-14:00", "10:00-14:00",
];
// rework $arr - give it days as keys
$dow = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$dow[$key]] = $value;
    unset($arr[$key]);
}

// rotate array
$day = 'saturday'; // start array with saturday
$shift = array_search($day, $dow);
$arr = array_merge(array_slice($arr, $shift, NULL, true), array_slice($arr, 0, $shift, true));
```

Note: the nifty one-liner that does the rotate magic is from: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php#105907

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/MCFe0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP date() function, to get the current day of the week (0=Sunday, 6=Saturday). You can either adjust your current array to operate from Sunday to Saturday, or you can adjust the array element # when you get the element(s) from the array.

date("w") will return the day of the week.

For a complete explanation of the PHP date() function, see this documentation...

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

This was fun, a little inventive use of 2 for loops will do this for you

```
function baseOnDay($day)
{
    $open = ['08:00-18:00', '08:00-18:00', '08:00-18:00', '08:00-18:00', 
             '08:00-18:00', '10:00-14:00', '10:00-14:00'
            ];
    $days = ['monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday',
            'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'
            ];
    $day = strtolower($day);
    if (!in_array($day, $days)) {
        return false;   // passed a silly param
    }
    
    $newOpen = [];
    $start = array_search($day, $days);
    for ($i=$start; $i<count($open); $i++){
        $newOpen[] = $open[$i];
    }
    for ($i=0; $i<$start; $i++){
        $newOpen[] = $open[$i];
    }
    return $newOpen;
}

if ( ($openTimes = baseOnDay('saturday')) !== false ){
    print_r($openTimes);
} else {
    echo 'Bad Parameter';
}
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10:00-14:00
    [1] => 10:00-14:00
    [2] => 08:00-18:00
    [3] => 08:00-18:00
    [4] => 08:00-18:00
    [5] => 08:00-18:00
    [6] => 08:00-18:00
)
```

Comment: It sounded as if he wanted to display the open hours, from the current day, forward.

If you make that array Sunday through Saturday, you can automatically return the array without needing any input, using date("w")

If you wanted to leave the function able to return different sets, you could change the input to numeric, using the same correlations as the date("w") function.

That way, the user could pass in the value of date("w") or a different start day.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is always Monday through Sunday and indexed 0 through 6, then just extract the one you want to the end and add it to the beginning of what's left. Saturday is 5 so remove that to the end:

```
$result = array_merge(array_splice($array, 5), $array);
```